# Docker run gives "CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)"

Tags: asp.net, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am very new to docker. And I am trying to dockerize a helloworld API.
But when I tried to docker run the image, I got this error:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
> response from daemon: container
> f891d7fc7af6e1183256043e6105fc87e25c6959d9745cc972b42c7b2e6f5a06
> encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system
> call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) [Event Detail:
> Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] [Event Detail:
> Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] [Event Detail:
> vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(168)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF683797B25:
> (caller: 00007FF68377A312) Exception(4) tid(108) 80070002 The system
> cannot find the file specified.
> CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\ComputeSystemManager_ExecuteProcess\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
> Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info:
> {"CommandLine":"dotnet
> HelloWorldDocker.dll","WorkingDirectory":"C:\app\bin","Environment":{"COMPLUS_NGenProtectedProcess_FeatureEnabled":"0","ROSLYN_COMPILER_LOCATION":"c:\\RoslynCompilers\\tools"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}.

I have a simple asp.net api. And I have it published to the same folder `./publish` 
And here is my docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./publish .
WORKDIR bin
RUN ls
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloWorldDocker.dll"]
```

`ls` shows that the `HelloWorldDocker.dll` is in the directory `./bin (app/bin)`. IDK what is wrong here...

Comment: Perhaps it is "dotnet" that cannot be found. If you get into the container with `docker exec -it <containerName> bash` and you try to run the `dotnet` command, does it work?

Comment: @IlyaY the problem seems to be windows container specific and the container is not starting. so no luck with that. Xuyue Shi did you find a solution to that. I am facing a similiar issue.

Comment: Thanks for responding. And @rominator007, you are correct, its a windows container issue. I tried to deploy it to a linux env. There is no problem at all...

Comment: @XuyueShi alright. I was having an issue where the container would start with docker run <image> but not with docker run <image> --name <name>. Turned out you have to start it with docker run --name <name> <image> *facepalm*

Comment: I have the exact same issue but I cannot run it on linux. dotnet command is not found. I go by path and then whatever I put next is nt found (e.g. I put dotnet test then again not found, even -h throws the exception)

Comment: While going in the docker container with -i everything works smoothly

Answer (score 2):

This line `COPY ./publish .` will copy all publish files into your current work directory.  The bin folder that contains your DLL now lives here: `/app/bin/{your dll}`.

It is not necessary to then change the work dir to bin like you did; instead, you could either leave your work dir alone (stay in /app) and specify your entrypoint as:
`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "./bin/HelloWorldDocker.dll"]`

-OR-

You could set your WORKDIR to `/app/bin` and specify your entrypoint as you already did: `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloWorldDocker.dll"]`

The main thing you need to keep in mind is where the files are in relation to your workdir, which you can manage by changing your workdir as well as copying files, as you did by copying all publish files into /app

Answer (score 2):

this may happen when you are rebuilding the image , in fact when you build a docker image it creates some intermediate containers and images so by deleting these containers and images  from the previous build fail it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent 1.5 days to resolve that. A lot of sources say it has been issue with user access on windows and I am tired to create/reassigned user's permissions. So small fix and it works!

Answer (score 2):

In the runner `config.toml`, my runner was configured to use the shell `pwsh`.

I replaced it with `powershell` and it worked.

The error comes from the fact that, for whatever reason, `pwsh` is not available.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was with this error (little similar):

Command: `docker run -it henriqueholtz/node-win:16.15.1 cmd`

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container 1edc7d95388e28604239457fd47ced188b968ab825f8da400c8bea84cfbb7ceb encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(174)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF744D6C00A: (caller: 00007FF744D3ECEA) Exception(2) tid(368) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\ComputeSystemManager_ExecuteProcess\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

#### How I've fix it?

After some hours trying with no success, I've removed all similar images, pulled the image again (in my case from docker hub), and then it worked.