# Why is "docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809 echo hello" giving me cannot find the file specified?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-container

Simply put, running `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809 echo hello` on a basic windows server core image gives me the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container b4e3e78ec07637c061407e28a24065d723ae20e1ef325c7c71fd3e40e06cdf58 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF644139FAB: (caller: 00007FF6440EE19A) Exception(2) tid(394) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

What could be causing this issue? If I add "cmd" before the echo hello it doesn't give an error anymore, but I do not see that the command was executed. I only see C:\ being printed.

Comment: did you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453478/docker-run-gives-createprocess-failure-in-a-windows-system-call-the-system-ca, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72234603/windows-docker-encountered-an-error-during-hcsshimsystemcreateprocess-failu or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306274/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-running-ecs-fargate-task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `echo hello` on `cmd`, because directly the system think that `echo` is an executable, when actually the `echo` is a command of `cmd` on windows. For example you can't execute `echo` from Task Scheduler, but you can run cmd from it.

Summary, you can run the container with the command below:

```
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809 cmd /c echo Hello
```

The command above will run cmd with the command `echo Hello` as you wanted.

See the evidency:

[image: examples with erro and without error]